# CRLF removed from Named Functions in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

It seems that in the past 48 hours (30th July'23) Google now automatically strips the CRLF from the formulas in 'Named Functions'.  If they have then I certainly understand the logic for doing this but before I resign myself to having to keep GIT copies of my named functions via vscode (in order to keep the formatting) I'm checking with the community for a second opinion to verify this is real or whether I've broken something my side.

I either need to spend more time fixing something my side or refactor all my functions into apps script - which will be fine but dull at this stage of the project. I get the same unformatted result when using NotePad++.

To add context. I create verbose, rather than complex, Named Functions to use as Lambdas in the MAP formula. This is mainly for data normalising so it's quite simple but has long lists of regex conditionals.  I use vscode to cut/copy/paste similar formulas within the single Named Function. My formulas when broken down into statements have between 80 to 100 lines. Up to today my method has been to scrape the code from the Named Function edit sidebar, paste it into vscode, make the edits then scrape it from vscode back into the Named Function edit sidebar and save it there.  Today all the formatting seems to be being striped out in the sidebar so the so the round robin is no longer efficient.

I completely accept I may be the only person in the world who works like this but if there is anyone who can share their experience or opinions on this I'd be happy to hear.

See this shared sheet for an example Named Function.
[example Named Function](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GHiDpLjicGxeKG8Dw-decwq6aNKNIsDjEF_cvdXODPM/edit?usp=sharing)